# Kendo UI Grid: Filter doesn't work if the value is mapped to 0

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-grid

We are facing filter issue on Kendo Grid when filter value is mapped to 0, below is the piece of code.

(We are applying existing filters to the new datasource to get the expected result)

**Code:**

```
  var filter = {};
  if ($("#FoodGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter()) {
       filter.filter = $("#FoodGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter();
  }

var query = kendo.data.Query.process(BulkTaggingDataSource.read.data(), filter);

 $.each(query.data, function (index, content) {
         $.each(query.data, function (index, content) {
                   if ($.inArray(content.id, checkedIds) < 0) {
                       checkedIds[content.id] = state;
                   }
         })
   })
});
```

**Filter which we get from $("#FoodGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter(): is**

[image]

In our case if the {field: 'TotalHours', operator: 'eq', value: '0'} if the filter value is '0'
we get the query.data as empty array and we wont get the expected result.

and filter will work if the {field: 'TotalHours', operator: 'eq', value: '5'}

we are facing issue only for '0' filter. and in schema we have declared 'TotalHours' as number.

Kindly let us know how to fix this issue.

Comment: what in 1,2 array in filter. Is this apply in result?

Comment: can you add this in fiddle or code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I did this way. Filter the value on a particular column like

There is checkbox and based on check/uncheck, the data filter on a column.

```
function AC_onlyStatementsShow() {
    var kgrid = $("#GrdLedger").data("kendoGrid");
    
    if ($('#checkIsOnlyStatement').prop("checked")) {
        kgrid.dataSource.filter({  //datasource filter apply on below condition
            field: "Treatment",            //column name on which filter apply
            operator: function (item) {
                return item == "Stmt"           //value to filter
            },
        });
    }
    else {
        kgrid.dataSource.filter({
            field: "Treatment",
            operator: function (item) {
                return item != "Stmt"
            },
        });
    }
}
```